# am getting NotFittedError: This MultinomialNB instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: machine-learning

my code is
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

ps = PorterStemmer()

def transform_text(text):
text = text.lower()
text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

```
y = []
for i in text:
    if i.isalnum():
        y.append(i)

text = y[:]
y.clear()

for i in text:
    if i not in stopwords.words('english') and i not in string.punctuation:
        y.append(i)

text = y[:]
y.clear()

for i in text:
    y.append(ps.stem(i))

return " ".join(y)
```

tfidf = pickle.load(open('vectorizer.pkl','rb'))
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

st.title("Email/SMS Spam Classifier")

input_sms = st.text_area("Enter the message")

if st.button('Predict'):

```
# 1. preprocess
transformed_sms = transform_text(input_sms)
# 2. vectorize
vector_input = tfidf.transform([transformed_sms])
# 3. predict
result = model.predict(vector_input)[0]
# 4. Display
if result == 1:
    st.header("Spam")
else:
    st.header("Not Spam")
```

Comment: Please wrap your code in ''' (add triple ' before and after) so it is properly visible. Add traceback to illustrate which part of the code generated the error.